# Double click fires event twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a quiz project where a user selects a multiple choice answer (radio button) and then click a link to proceed to the next question. If a radio button has not been selected, the link cannot be clicked. Once a radio button is selected and a link clicked, the next question is pulled from a MySQL database using AJAX.

The issue I am having is that if a user double clicks the link, a question is skipped. So if you are on question 1 and double click the link, question 3 is loaded instead of 2.

Is there a way in jQuery to make an event fire only once, if a link is single or double clicked?

Thanks

```
$('#next-question-click').on( "click", function(){
if ($('[name="radio-question"]').is(':checked')){
    var answer = $(".question-content ul li input:checked + label").text();
    question_number = question_number + 1;

    if(question_number<100){
        next_question(question_number);
    }
} else {
    $("#error-text").html('Please select an answer.');
}
    return false;
})

.on("dblclick", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();  //cancel system double-click event
});
```

Comment: Most likely your code just need a small tweak, so why don't you post your code and we will see what's wrong with it

Comment: how are you triggering the events ???  you must unbind the event first and bind it again. This is the common mistake that most of us do.

Comment: @Huangism thanks - I have edited the question and posted my code

Comment: @badcoder updated with my answer

Answer (score 2):

You just need to gate the execution by adding a class. So your code will only execute if the current question is not being changed.

Now, **ideally you should remove the active class from `$('#next-question-click')` in the success function of your ajax call to load the new question to ensure the function will only execute after the new question has been loaded**

The advantage of adding a class is so that it will not pollute the global variable space, as to what class to add, it is up to you. I just used active as an example

```
$('#next-question-click').on("click", function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        if ($('[name="radio-question"]').is(':checked')) {
            $(this).addClass('active');
            var answer = $(".question-content ul li input:checked + label").text();
            question_number++;

            if (question_number < 100) {
                next_question(question_number);
                $(this).removeClass('active'); // this should go into the success/complete function of the ajax call
            }
        } else {
            $("#error-text").html('Please select an answer.');
        }
    }

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function is what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried this, but then it prevents the link from being clicked after question 2, since the whole system loads via Ajax, i.e. the page does not refresh.

Comment: Yeah you will have to re-bind the event handler after the ajax call if you want to use `one()`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of unbinding and rebinding events, I usually use a variable as a flag.
Something like this...

```
var working = false;
$('#next-question-click').on( "click", function(){

    if (working) return false; //Dont do anything, basically.

    if ($('[name="radio-question"]').is(':checked')){
        var answer = $(".question-content ul li input:checked + label").text();
        question_number = question_number + 1;

        if(question_number<100){
            working = true;
            next_question(question_number);
        }
    } else {
        $("#error-text").html('Please select an answer.');
    }

    return false;
})
```

And, on the next_question function, after the next question is loaded and ready to be answered, you would add `working = false;`